Can Tonelli or Fubini Be Used to Interchange Limits in a Summation?
I am analyzing the following double limit:
$$
\lim_{p \to 0^+} \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^p},
$$
where $A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$ (not disjoint, but I can group them as disjoint if necessary)and $u(A_n)$ represents the measure of the set $A_n$. The measure $u$ satisfies $u(A_n) \geq 0$. My goal is to show that the limits can be interchanged:
$$
\lim_{p \to 0^+} \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^p} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{p \to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^p}.
$$
My  observations:

For fixed $p > 0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u(A_n)}{n^p}$ converges because $n^{-p}$ decays geometrically.
As $p \to 0^+$, $n^{-p} \to 1$, so $\frac{u(A_n)}{n^p} \to u(A_n)$ pointwise.
I believe Tonelli's Theorem can justify the interchange of the limits because:

$\frac{u(A_n)}{n^p} \geq 0$, which satisfies Tonelli's condition for non-negativity.
The pointwise limit exists: $\lim_{p \to 0^+} \frac{u(A_n)}{n^p} = u(A_n)$.



My question:
Can Tonelli's Theorem (or Fubini's Theorem) be applied in this situation to justify the interchange of limits? If not, is there another theorem that provides a better justification?
Update: Now, I am thinking maybe the use of Dominated convergence theorem or Monotone convergence theorem.

Tonelli's theorem doesn't seem to work; it's not clear what integral $\lim_{p \to 0^+}$ can refer to.
Monotone convergence theorem would work however.

Could you elaborate please why MCT would work here?

EDIT: Thanks for dummy for catching my slip-up regarding the MCT portion of my answer.
I'll first provide a "non-measure-theoretical" answer and then one based on the monotone convergence theorem. The quotation marks are there because the first answer is actually just be reproving the MCT in this situation, it was only different from the MCT in the previous version due to a big mistake on my end.
The lemma we need is actually something I've proved in one of my earliest answers on this site, namely is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{i \in I}(x^n_i) =\sup_{i \in I}(\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n_i)$? for each i, $x_i^n$ is a monotone increasing sequence., and although no one proofchecked that answer back then, I don't think I've missed anything. You can also find its series variant on Wikipedia.

Lemma: consider a doubly indexed sequence $(a_{m,n})_{m,n}$ such that $a_{m,n} \leq a_{m+1,n}$ for all $m$ and all $n$.
Then we have:
$$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \sup_n a_{m,n} = \sup_n \lim_{m \to +\infty} a_{m,n}$$

Short version of the proof: the trick is to observe that the increasingness condition simply implies that both limits in the equality exist as limits of increasing sequences, so that it comes down to:
$$\sup_m \sup_n a_{m,n} = \sup_n \sup_m a_{m,n}$$
which is true.
The premise is now simple: choose $(p_m)_m$ a decreasing sequence tending to $0^+$. For all $m$ and all $n$, we have:
$$\frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_m}} \leq \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_{m+1}}}$$
so that, for all $m$ and $N$:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_m}} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_{m+1}}}$$
Taking $a_{m,N} := \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_m}}$ in the lemma above and using the non-negativeness of the terms $u(A_n)$ to guarantee that the sum of the involved series is the supremum of their partial sums, we obtain:
$$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_m}} = \lim_{m \to +\infty} \sup_N a_{m,N} = \sup_N \lim_{m \to +\infty} a_{m,N} = \sup_N \sum_{n = 1}^N u(A_n) =\sum_{n = 1}^\infty u(A_n)$$
and we are done justifying the swap of the limits.

Let's now see why we could use the monotone convergence theorem here as suggested by dummy in the comments above.
Said theorem would be applied to the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}^*$ the set of strictly positive integers, that is the measure $\mu $ on $\mathbb{N}^*$ which assigns to every $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}^*$ its cardinality $|A|$.
All nonnegative sequences $(u_n)_n$ are measurable functions because every set was taken as measurable, and the corresponding integrals $\int_{\mathbb{N}^*} u \,\mathrm{d}\mu$ are then nothing more than the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} u_n$, and this extends to "$\mu$-integrable" sequences, i.e. the usual $\ell^1$ sequences, although we won't need that since everything is nonnegative here.
The monotone convergence theorem translated in this particular situation is then the following statement:
Given a sequence $\left((u_{m,n})_n\right)_m$ of non-negative sequences satisfying $u_{m,n} \leq u_{m+1,n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and all $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have the existence and equality of the following quantities (which may be infinite):
$$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} u_{m,n} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \lim_{m \to +\infty} u_{m,n}$$
Now, let's go back to $(p_m)_m$ and the inequality $$\frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_{m+1}}} \leq \frac{u(A_n)}{n^{p_m}}$$
You can see that we can apply the theorem to our sequence, and thus get the same conclusion as before.

@dummy See, that's why I shouldn't write long answers at 1am. I looked at the theorem (which I don't use often compared to DCT, I'll admit), saw "pointwise non-decreasing sequence of functions", somehow read "decreasing"... Thanks for having noticed the issue!
